# Why can't a temporary be sent as ref args to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

This works:

```
class Foo {};
void external_function(Foo&);
void f() {
  Foo b;                                                                                                                                         
  external_function(b);                                                                                                                          
}
```

This does not:

```
class Foo {};
void external_function(Foo&);
void f() {
  external_function(Foo());
}
```

Clang says:

```
aac.cc:3:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Derived' to 'Base &' for 1st argument;
```

GCC is actually *more* helpful with:

```
aac.cc:7:30: error: invalid initialisation of non-const reference of type ‘Base&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Derived’
```

Herb Sutter (http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) says a non-const reference can't be used for rvalues, which makes sense in his example, but not in mine, since the object exists for the duration of the external_function() call, doesn't it?

I know how to make it work; Simply create a named object so that it's not an rvalue (as I did above), or use const ref. But I want to know *why* it's not allowed, since it seems safe to me.

Comment: Another way to make it work is to declare the argument to `external_function` as a `const` reference (as hinted to by the error from GCC).

Comment: Btw. this doesn't have anything to do with derived classes. Using just one class everywhere without any inheritance would simplify your question and reproduce the problem just as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot bind *any* kind of temporary to a non-const lvalue reference. Inheritance here is just a distraction.

```
struct Foo{};

void bar(Foo&) {}
void cbar(const Foo&) {}

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  bar(f);      // OK
  bar(Foo());  // ERROR
  cbar(Foo()); // OK: const reference binds to temporary
}
```

As to the ultimate "**why?"**, it simply deemed to be error prone to allow modification of an rvalue via an lvalue reference. Quoting from "*The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition*" §7.7.1

> References to variables and references to constants are distinguished because introducing a temporary for a variable would have been highly error-prone; an assignment to the variable would become an assignment to the - soon to dissappear - temporary. No such problem exists for references to constants...

Comment: One note: in C++11 you can bind a temporary to a r-value reference.

Comment: Doh. I've updated the question. But you've only confirmed that I can't, not, like I asked, why.

Comment: @Thomas you were asking "Why can't reference to temporary Derived be sent as Base ref args to a function in C++?". As to why you cannot bind a temporary non-const lvalue reference, I am not sure where the ultimate cause is documented. This is clearly set out in the C++ standard, and my interpretation is that it is semantically confusing and dangerous to allow modifications to a temporary via an lvalue reference, and that this kind of thing would be more likely to be a coding error rather than desired behaviour. So it is banned outright.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Your answer helped to clarify the question, which I very much appreciate, but didn't address why something that to me seems perfectly safe, isn't allowed. For example changing to using pointers instead of references this becomes just a warning (taking address of a temporary), but also seems safe in this case since the object isn't destroyed until after the function returns.

Comment: @Thomas The only reason I can find is that, in the opinion of the creator of C++, it is not perfectly safe to allow modification of a temporary via an lvalue reference. I added a quote from the CPPPL 4th edition.

Answer (score 2):

The "why" is to avoid difficult to detect bugs.  If the argument is not const, that means the function is planning to change it (otherwise just make it const!) Changing a temporary object is not likely to be what you intended and is often a very difficult to figure out bug.

Answer (score -1):

Because the Standard says so, as they believe it is likely to result in bugs (I disagree). There is no technical reason why it is not allowed.

Comment: It is error prone where there is an implicit convertion to a temporary. If the called function modify the object, then usually one need to get back changes. Usually when a rule like that exists, it is because it has caused many actual bugs and the impact of making the rule more strict is relatively minimal.